# Has AzMan been removed from Microsoft server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows, authorization, windows-server-2012, azman, netsqlazman

I am working on a legacy product which uses Microsoft AzMan for authorization. Recently, as part of the Windows Server 2012 R2 migration, I found that the breaking changes indicate that the AzMan has been removed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx

But after installation of Windows Server 2012 R2, I still find that the AzMan exists. I am little confused now.

My questions:
1.  Will  AzMan be actually removed by Microsoft in coming days (if not already in Windows server 2012 R2)?
2.  If Yes, then what is the best alternatives for AzMan.

I also checked an  [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) as an alternative to AzMan. It looks really interesting. Anybody has already used NetSqlAzMan ? Any drawbacks you see ?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Azman with Windows 2012 R2 and it works fine, even though it is deprecated.

Comment: We are using Azman with Windows Server 2016 and it still works fine.